# Не устанавливается NuGet пакет Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling

Tags: c#, telegram, nuget

Требуется пакет Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling для работы бота. Подключить бота к Form проекту, видел что у всех это работает. А у меня ни пакет не хочет устанавливаться, ни сам бот работать. Даже запустить не могу через `botClient.StartReceiving()`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Нет такого понятия как "не устанавливается" или "не работает" в программировании, есть четкие ошибки, логи, данные, код. Когда один программист говорит другому "не работает", лично для меня это является неуважение, троллингом, шуткой. Поэтому пожалуйста, как программист, предоставляйте все возможные данные! Вот например не устанавливается, почему? Что пишет? На какую платформу ставите? .NET Framework? Если да, то пакет для .NET6 только существует, его не установить на FW.

Comment: Я руководствовался тем, что у индуса из ютуба все прекрасно устанавливалось и работало в формах проекта. Уже разобрался, как обойтись без этого пакета.